# Spring Boot | How to change context URL of my application from 'gerp-tasks-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-wildfly10' to "terptasks" | Wildfly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly, wildfly-16

When i deploy Spring boot application in Wildfly.

I get following web context which is

```
2021-01-19 08:05:14,620 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 161) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP01 for context '/gerp-tasks-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-wildfly10'
2021-01-19 08:05:15,961 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 161) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/gerp-tasks-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-wildfly10' for server 'default-server'
```

This makes my URL somewhat like:

```
https://badardata.qa.shintegrator.cosng.net/gerp-tasks-rest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-wildfly10/tasks/all
```

How can i change web context url while deploy Spring Boot project in wildfly?

Structure of project is somewhat like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you know, by default the application context path is the same as the war name, for customization context path you should create `jboss-web.xml` inside `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` folder:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>terptasks</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```